# Golang Import Cycle Challenge

Tags: go, dependencies, package

I am having an issue with a cyclic dependency (import cycle not allowed) in my go code and not really sure the best way to resolve it.  I think my lack of understanding of golang interfaces might be impacting my ability to see the way forward.

My Issue  - I have Two Packages:

- **Event** - Event is mostly a "parent" and will make many calls into the workout package
- **Workout** - In one case I need to call the Event Package and this creates a cyclic dependency because Event already consumes Workout

What is the best way to allow Workout to call a function (not a method on an object) in the Event domain?

Below is my simplified code to help provide some context

```
//workout package
//This is a private function on the workout package that is 
//attempting to call a public function on the Event Package
func findWorkoutAssociatedToActivityTcx(txcObject *DataTcx) *EventWorkout{
    return event.GetEventByDate(txcObject.ActivityDate, "", "")
}
```

Is it possible to create an interface into that function?   I don't fully understand how I would do that.   Thank you very much.

//UPDATES - Code on attempting to setup an interface

```
//WorkoutPackage
//workout package
//This is a private function on the workout package that is
//attempting to call a public function on the Event Package
func findWorkoutAssociatedToActivityTcx(txcObject *DataTcx, userID, transactionID string) *Workout {
    //return event.GetEventByDate(txcObject.ActivityDate, "", "")
    MyEventFinder.GetEventByDate(txcObject.ActivityDate, userID, transactionID)
    return nil
}

var MyEventFinder EventFinder

type EventFinder interface {
    GetEventByDate(time.Time, string, string) (*sharedstructs.ListOfEvents, error)
}
```

//Event Package

```
type eventProvider struct{}

func (e eventProvider) GetEventByDate(date time.Time, userID, transactionID string) (*sharedstructs.ListOfEvents, error) {
        redFalconLogger.LogDebug("event.GetEventByDate: ", transactionID)
        if date.IsZero() || userID == "" {
            return nil, sharedstructs.InvalidData{Msg: "Invalid date or userID"}
        }
        //Create the query params
        queryParamArray, queryParamCreationError := createQueryParamForQueryByDate(&date, &userID)
        if queryParamCreationError != nil {
            return nil, queryParamCreationError
        }
        //perform the query - pass empty orderBy because I don't care
        queryResults, queryError := queryForEvent(*queryParamArray, "")
        if queryError != nil {
            switch queryError.(type) {
            case firestorehelper.UnqueryableCollection:
                return nil, sharedstructs.Forbidden{Msg: "operation is forbidden, probably due to malformed query"}
            default:
                return nil, sharedstructs.InternalServerError{Msg: "something went wrong in the query"}
            }
        }
        return queryResults, nil
    }
```

Comment: The returned type is *EventWorkout. Wouldn't you consider merging those packages if they're tightly coupled? Otherwise I'd create another package just to define interfaces that will be implemented by the structs from `event` package and replace the current return type with it.

Comment: @Berkant you don't need a third package to define interfaces, because an interface only needs to be referenced by the consuming package(s), not by the package(s) implementing it; and further, identical interfaces can be defined in multiple packages and will be equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are spot on that you can do this with an interface.  In the event package you need to give the GetEventByDate a receiver struct:

```
type eventProvider struct {}
func (e eventProvider) GetEventByDate(t time.Time, a, b string) *workout.EventWorkout{...}
```

Then in the workout package:

```
type EventFinder interface {
    GetEventByDate(time.Time, string, string) *EventWorkout
}
```

You can then pass an `eventProvider` instance into the workout package and use that just via the `EventFinder` interface that has no compile time dependency on the `event` package.  You don't show how you call into the `workout` package but this could either be as a parameter to a method call or setting it when constructing a struct in the workout package.

Comment: Thank you very much!   This is exactly what I was hoping to do.   I guess I am still a bit wooly on the how to populate my interface in my workout package.

Should I be doing it on init() of event package?   Will that work for testing?  I actually tried something like that and got a nil reference error.  Will try what you are suggesting though.  

Thank you

Comment: How are you calling into the workout package at the moment, I've assumed that things originate in the event package and then flow into workout, if that is the case just construct an instance of eventProvider and pass it on when you call into the workout package

Comment: For the most part that is true but both event and workout have separate API's on top of them so someone could go directly to the Workout (bypassing the Event).   I kept them as separate packages becasue I want to be able to easily separate and microservice them at a later date.

Maybe the best way is to have the init() function of Event populate the EventFinder interface in the workout package?   Not sure if that will work for running tests though?

Comment: Updated the OP with more code if it helps, truly appreciate your thoughts here

Comment: Hmm, that is trickier then, the init function on an event package will only get called when something calls into the event so if the first call into your system goes to workout then there will be no trigger to get that var set up.  The other option is to have a third package that both event and workout rely on that just contains the GetEventByDate function.

Comment: Thank you very much.    This explains why I was having an issue getting my interface working.   I appreciate your help.  It clarified a lot.